# How do I reference an appendix when it is defined with \chapter*?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, numbering, starred-version

I have a problem with the reference of an annex. In the main `.tex` file I put

```
%... couple of lines before this
\include{ThesisChapter4} % 
\include{ThesisAppendixA} % Appendix A
```

and in `Appendix A` I write this:

```
\chapter*{Appendix A}
\label{ThesisAppendixA} \thispagestyle{plain} %\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{images/heike/img1}
 \label{image1}
\end{figure}
```

In the page of ThesisChapter4, I tried to refer to the chapter of Appendix A with this:

```
 A complete procedure is provided in chapter \ref{chap:Appendix A}.
```

However, when I look at the created PDF, this is shown as

```
 A complete procedure is provided in chapter ??.
```

I have actually managed to refer to different figures before, however so far these refer to labels in the same file (for instance, in thesis chapter 4, I refer to a certain figure in the thesis chapter 4). When I tried to reference to chapter Appendix A, it fails. I tried to refer to the label also (image1) but it also fails.

Does anyone know how to fix above problem?

Comment: Your label is `ThesisAppendixA`, not `chap:Appendix A`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, I am aware of that . However, if I do this, the result is "A complete procedure is provided in chapter 4.4" where 4.4 being my current section. I tried to have a result of "..in chapter Appendix A" instead

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. That would be because you're using an unnumbered chapter (I didn't notice at first). You could perhaps add the `nameref` package, and use `... is provided in \nameref{ThesisAppendixA}`, but it doesn't solve the figure reference. Depending on document class, you may have an `\appendix` command, that switches the numbering of subsequent chapters to A, B, C etc., instead of 1, 2, 3. Then you can use a numbered chapter, and refer to it as usual. Which class are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't make a reference to a `\chapter*`, because it is unnumbered.

Answer (score 12):

The general way of utilizing appendix chapters is to issue `\appendix` once before using the regular `\chapter{...}` for each appendix. What `\appendix` does (in the standard [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) document classes) is:

```
\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
```

This

- Restarts the chapter counter numbering (`\setcounter{chapter}{0}`);
- Restarts the section counter numbering (`\setcounter{section}{0}`). This is usually done automatically when you "make a new `\chapter`" (actually, via a `\[ref]stepcounter`), but not when you just set a counter as is done in the previous step;
- Modifies the chapter heading to read `Appendix <num>` (actually `\appendixname\ <num>`) rather than `Chapter <num>`; and
- Modifies the chapter counter to be CAPITALIZED alphabetic (A, B, C, ...).

That way you don't have to use `\chapter*{Appendix A}` but rather something more symbolic like `\chapter{Pseudocode}` that includes a name for the particular appendix. Using the latter, you can now reference the appendix in the usual way you would a regular chapter, since it is numbered with a referenceable counter.